# Sklearn Preprocessing -- *** TypeError: No matching signature found

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, normalize

I am trying to normalize a CSR matrix,

but I get this error: `(*** TypeError: No matching signature found).`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
normalize(x_m, norm="l2", axis=1)
```

The matrix is 609186x849632 sparse matrix of type 'numpy.float16'
    with 189140200 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format

Comment: Yes, looks like np.float16 are not supported consistently in scipy. One [issue is here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7408)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually I solved the problem. I think it is because of the data type. Changing `np.float16`  to `np.float32`, solved the problem. I do not know why, this problem only happens with `np.float16` data type.

Comment: same error happens for pandas with float16 instead of float32.

Answer (score 3):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

columns_changed = []

for col in df.columns:
    col_type = x_m[col].dtypes
    if col_type == 'float16':
      columns_changed.append(col)
      x_m[col] = x_m[col].astype(np.float32)

normalize(x_m, norm="l2", axis=1)

for col in columns_changed:
  x_m[col] = x_m[col].astype(np.float16)

x_m
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

In case it will be of use to anybody, I encountered this error when using generalized linear models from sklearn.linear_model, namely, PoissonRegressor and GammaRegressor (the error was raised somewhere in loss.py submodule of sklearn). There was only one target variable, so, as we usually do it for sklearn models, I made `.reshape((-1, 1))` or the equivalent slicing `[:, None]`, whatever. And, surprisingly, this was causing the error: when I removed that target vector reshape, the error disappeared at a cost of well known sklearn warnning about 1D shape of an array :)