# TypeError: No matching signature found, when tryint to pivot dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a dataframe,

```
df

    ID   UD     MD    TD
1    1    3     13.0  115
2    1    4     14.0  142
3    2    3     13.0  156
4    2    8     13.5  585
```

I get the error. `TypeError: No matching signature found`, when I try `df_p = df.pivot('ID','UD','MD')`

What could be wrong ?

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52345236/sklearn-preprocessing-typeerror-no-matching-signature-found) maybe

Answer (score 4):

here is the data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,1,2,2], 'UD': [3,4,3,8], 'MD':[13,14,13,13.5], 'TD':[115,142,156,585]})
```

by default in python 3.9 the dtypes are as following

```
ID      int64
UD      int64
MD    float64
TD      int64
dtype: object
```

and you can run `df.pivot('ID','UD','MD')`

```
UD  3   4   8
ID          
1   13.0    14.0    NaN
2   13.0    NaN 13.5
```

but if you by a chance have read the data as `float16`

```
df.astype({'MD':np.float16}).pivot('ID','UD','MD')
```

you would get the `TypeError: No matching signature found`

Comment: That's great ! :)

Comment: What if one want to pivot the df and keep the values' data type as np.float16? I'm trying to reduce the computation load and have everything in the float16 type. However, I cannot use pivot except when every value is in float64.

Comment: @mitramirshafiee can you slice your big df into smaller chunks and pivot each separately and then merge ? perhaps you get more solutions if you make a new question specifically on how to do faster pivoting on py3.9 given these changes

Comment: @Areza I'm using matrix multiplication in SVG for recommending donation opportunities to people. Therefore, I need to have all the projects (columns) and people (rows) to calculate similar people in collaborate filtering. Thanks anyways, I'll look into possible solutions.